# Where to ask stuff you can't ask here?

Tags: discussion

I intend this question as a clearinghouse of polite ways to complete the sentence, "You can take your question and ..."

... visit [someplace else].

Where can you go for shopping recs? Where do you go for song identification? Where do find more songs like your new favorite song?

Comment: There are two related proposals on A51: [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46533/music-fans?referrer=BIBzX_l1C3s-eTRFb3JXLQ2) and [Music](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49254/music?referrer=uyex1nS_Vqo7Gt066JLmDA2)

Comment: Although Music has 3 followers, and a strong comment that it is a clash with Music fans and this site :-)

Comment: [Where to find sheet music?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/696/sites-with-a-good-selection-of-sheet-music) has already been asked.

Comment: related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/457/where-can-one-get-songs-identified

Answer (score 3):

We now have [MusicFans.StackExchange](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/).

It's still StackExchange. Same basic rules: Q-and-A, *not* a **forum**, but a different focus within the broad topic of Music.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for related songs, there's [Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/). It can dig up some nice stuff.

Comment: It's US limited though it was very nice back then when it was free internationally. For an alternative I can recommend http://whatthefuckshouldilistentonow.com/ if you don't mind the slang. It's powered by Lastfm and is pretty handy.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of our off-topic and non-constructive questions might fit here: http://www.quora.com/Music